# Handling NSData (Data) range exceptions

Tags: swift, exception, swift3, nsdata

Using `NSData` (or `Data`) for reading bytes using `getBytes` (`copyBytes`) can throw NSRangeException. I don't know how to catch them.

I know that for `NS` classes, including `NSData`, I would have to use Objective-C wrapper to catch and handle exception but I am a bit surprised to see that `Data` also throws exception that Swift cannot handle natively.

Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way I can catch those using pure Swift? Or is there any other method that throws Swift handleable errors?

Code example that fails (in reality I am using data created from file)

```
// Using NSData

let dataBytes:[UInt8] = [0xff, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22]
let data = NSData(bytes: dataBytes, length: dataBytes.count)
let dataRange = NSRange(location: 2, length: 4)

var result = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)

do
{
    try data.getBytes(&result, range: dataRange)
    print("OK")
}
catch
{
    print("FAIL")
}


// Using Data

let dataBytes:[UInt8] = [0xff, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22]
let data = Data(dataBytes)
let dataRange = Range(2..<6)

var result = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)

do
{
    try data.copyBytes(to: &result, from: dataRange)
    print("OK")
}
catch
{
    print("FAIL")
}
```

Note: Code in question also shows two warnings (as expected, because Swift is not capable of handling those) but I added those `try...catch` block just to show what I want to use.

> No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression
>
> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block

Comment: `Data copyBytes` doesn't throw so there's nothing to catch.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, that is the crux of the problem. It does not throw but it crashes the app. Leaning on Objective-C is like having three legged horse in race track... Is there a way around this? Using copyBates is not imperative - it is about functionality it provides.

Comment: `NSRangeException` cannot be caught at runtime with a `do-try-catch` flow.  It's a programming error, you're going out of range of a collection type.

Comment: You don't catch the exception, you prevent it with a proper `if` statement.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, thanks... that is not exactly the answer I wanted to hear, but at least I know my options now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that the the upper index of the range you're using isn't out of range for your Data:

```
if dataRange.upperBound <= data.count {
    data.copyBytes(to: &result, from: dataRange)
}
```

You can think of `Data` more like an array/collection. `copyBytes` will fail without a catchable exception for the same reason `anArray[1]` will fail for a single item array.